# How to use Jasmine spies on a service with static variable?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

In my ANGULAR 2 application there is a service; that contains a static reference property.

```
export class AppConfigService {
    static settings: IAppConfig;
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    load() {
        const jsonFile = `assets/config/config.${environment.name}.json`;
        return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http.get(jsonFile).toPromise().then((response: IAppConfig) => {
                AppConfigService.settings = response as IAppConfig;
                resolve();
            }).catch((response: any) => {
                reject(`Could not load file '${jsonFile}': ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

And here is a sample implementation of the method I am going to test in my ts file.

```
export class SlideImageComponent implements OnInit {
    ......
    readonly baseUrl = AppConfigService.settings.serverApiUrl;
    ......
```

How can I mock the data in the static variable for the test cases? Whenever I try to mock the data in useClass/useValue format, I am getting a undefined value for AppConfigService.settings.serverApiUrl.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript static variables don't exist in JS.

Instead, they're bound to the class constructor.

Try using this :

```
AppConfigService.constructor.settings.serverApiUrl
```

Comment: sorry, my implementation work well, I came the error  only if I run a test.

Comment: Well if you deduct from my answer, to mock the data, it would be `Object.assign(AppConfigService.constructor, { value: { settings: { ... }}})`